# One database on Linux and Windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, mysql

I want to use MySQL database on my Ubuntu installation as of Windows 7, It should be dynamically, I mean when I change data in database on Ubuntu it should save also on Windows too.

I've already changed datadir in my

```
/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
```

and

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

to Windows path like this:

```
/media/Data/xampp/mysql/data
```

But it still doesn't work.

How can I connect to database from Windows installation?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a database server such as MySQL you can't do what you're asking. From what I can see you ARE using MySQL. For both to access the database and it remain synchronised you will need to run a separate database server on your network.

There are a number of solutions, some easy (like a separate server on your network) and some harder to implement (running Windows in a VM and using your Linux as the host and MySQL server to serve Windows; or running some export/import system when your OSes start and shutdown so during start they can synchronise... The latter is a pretty pointless solution because of how inefficient it is and the high risk of data corruption and loss).

Another solution is a flat file database system that works with both Windows and Linux...

Comment: What about Mysql Replication on localhost is it possible?

Comment: Replication usually requires two live servers that can talk to each other and stay synchronised. Emphasis on "live". You're dual-booting which means at any one time you are only ever running one server.

Comment: So I can't have live database on two systems.